# Rails production static files routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static, heroku

When I run my app locally in test/dev my views come up nicely and everything is happy. When I try to navigate to those same erb files running on my remote server/local production server I get errors like the following:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/stylesheets/scaffold.css")
```

I've seen similar questions here on SO but none have been able to solve my problem. The closest thing I've found to an answer is the first answer here: [Rails 404 error for Stylesheet or JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410956/rails-404-error-for-stylesheet-or-javascript-files)

As I understand it the best thing to do would be to configure my webserver to serve static files. How do I do this locally/on Heroku?

**Update**

As per raidfive's suggestion I changed config.serve_static_assets from false to true and this fixed my issue. However, I see that it says in production.rb that Apache or nginx should already be serving static assets. Is it any less good/professional to serve static assets in this way and if so how would I achieve the desired results if I'm using Heroku?

**Update 2**

Apparently Heroku [does this automatically](http://docs.heroku.com/rails3#serving-static-assets), I had an extra comma that was causing the mischief. I was able to look in the extended Heroku logs using the [following tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671454/heroku-how-to-see-all-the-logs/2672296#2672296) to track down the trouble. Thanks SO!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Are you using Rails 3? By default Rails 3 / webrick does not serve static files in production mode. You can easily enable this by setting

`config.serve_static_assets` to `true` in your `production.rb` file.

Comment: Ah ha, I thought it might be something like that. I noticed in the comment above the setting, however, that it says that apache or nginx should already do this. Is there something I should be setting in my server?

Comment: Ignore that, apparently it's something Heroku does automatically. My issue was the errant placement of a comma that for some reason my local server was ignoring. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah, no problem. Yea, I think Heroku has a doc page about how they handle static assets if you want to read into it.

Comment: I modified the `config/environments/production.rb` per the above suggestion to serve static assets but still get a 404 error for a heroku deployed app (landing page or root).

Answer (score 2):

In Rails5, you should comment

```
"config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?"
```

in `config/enviroment/production.rb`